# Elementary limits, from left and right.

Tags: limits

The intuitive with limits and their direction from left and right
[image]

Comment: Um, what is your question?

Comment: Well, obviously explain where I go wrong because my reasoning gives opposite result the correct result. I get negative infiniti when is should be positive and vice versa.

Comment: you can make a of values tabulation, for left and right.

Comment: Hmm.. I see what first looked like a scan from a textbook was actually your question _as a picture_. Why on earth are you posting it that way, instead of as actual readable text?

Comment: What format is used for code in stack exchange, cause when i copy from etc. mathematica it comes out as code and not as i want it to look like?

Comment: See [MathJax help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Comment: I think we're being a little hard on this asker, because he really did give his work. (I typically agree with the "close first, ask questions later" crowd, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got the directions mixed up a little.

In (1), you are approaching from the *right*. So the denominator will approach like $2+x$ where $x$ goes from $\infty$ to $-2$. These values are all positive, so the denominator is positive, rather than negative.